# Azure Media Services: Provide custom file names for the asset files

Tags: azure, encoding, azure-blob-storage, azure-media-services

I'm encoding a video file using the built-in adaptive streaming transform. Once the file is successfully processed, an asset container is created with the below files:

[image]

Is it possible to provide custom file names at the time a job is created? It seems that the default behavior is to take a certain number of characters from the original file name and prepend them in the above file names. If possible, I'd like to configure this behavior.

P.S. I'm using the .NET SDK.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom transform to output file names differently.  On https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/media/transforms/createorupdate#definitions search for the Mp4Format section.  In that you can specify the filenamePattern with certain macros like {Bitrate} and {Codec}.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/custom-preset-cli-howto for an example custom transform and the process by which to create it in Media Services.

Comment: Thanks. For your second link, where do I find documentation on those JSON properties (e.g. complexity, referenceFrames, profile, etc.)?

Comment: Those are on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/previous/media-services-mes-schema.

Answer (score 0):

I use the macros on my jobs, they work ok. I have a process that takes 3 videos (an intro section, the actual content, and the outro section) and encodes them as one single video. The issue I have with the macros is that it uses the file name of the first video in the inputs. So it ends up using the file name of the intro video which is a generic name. They need to have a way where we can have a little more control.

I suppose I could copy/rename the intro video to a desired name before I encode and it would pick it up, but that seems to be a little bit of overkill.

The Macros are good, but they could use some enhancements I think.